# Not able to login into the website https://www.spotontrack.com/login using selenium webdriver through Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to login using selenium web driver on this site:https://www.spotontrack.com/login.

I have filled in all the details.
But,when I try to click on the login button, I get this error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="submit"]"}
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.spotontrack.com/login')
print(browser.current_url)
browser.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys('b7654169@urhen.com')
browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('.....')
submit_button = browser.find_element_by_name('submit')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
submit_button.click()
```

Comment: Did you just post your password on a public website?

Comment: https://www.spotontrack.com/terms-of-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To login into the website `https://www.spotontrack.com/login` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block(using css_selector):

  ```
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get("https://www.spotontrack.com/login")
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']"))).send_keys('b7654169@urhen.com')
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']").send_keys('b7654169@urhen.com')
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
  ```
- Code Block(using xpath):

  ```
  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get("https://www.spotontrack.com/login")
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='email']"))).send_keys('b7654169@urhen.com')
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys('b7654169@urhen.com')
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spotontrack]